# Why does qpython say "No module named sl4a"?

Tags: system, qpython

1. Install QPython from Google Play store
2. Open QPython, slide right and click "Console"
3. Try some code, starting with `import androidhelper`

   u0_a98@android:/ $ python
   Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 3 2013, 20:01:13)
   [GCC 4.4.3] on darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   > > > import androidhelper
   > > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
   > > >         File "", line 1, in 
   > > >         File "/storage/sdcard0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/site-packages/androidhelper.py", line 43, in 
   > > >           import sl4a
   > > >       ImportError: No module named sl4a

I'm running Cyanogenmod 10.0.0, Android 4.1.2.  Any idea how to import androidhelper successfully?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable in StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 4):

QPython is still Beta so you'll need to look around for documentation.

I think you haven't added any modules to your library so you'll need to do so for your code to work.

http://qpython.org/question/62/how-to-install-3rd-part-python-modules-for-qpython/

Answer (score 2):

I think the bug you describe only in console now,
But I am sure new version will fix this bug. : ) You can follow it's news on facebook http://www.facebook.com/QPython

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest from the Google Play store.  I'm not getting this error using QPython (classic, not QPython3).